# Make three divs (ordered horizontally and nested inside other divs) the same height

Tags: css, height

I have three articles aligned horizontally with the same structure:

date, title, event time, location, image, text, button

I want them to have the same height (based on the longest article) which I can get to work.

The problem I am having is that I want each section of the same height and the next section needs to start at the same height in all the three articles.
I tried many solution (css flex, grid) but I can't make them work because of the nested div structure (which is pre-generated by the CMS I am using).

Here is the code:

```html
<div id="container">
  <article id="node-1">
  
    <div class="event-start">
      <span class="event-year">2021</span>
      <span class="event-start-month">Feb</span>
      <span class="event-start-day">18</span>
    </div>
  
    <div class="event-content">
      <header class="node-header">
        <h1 class="event-title">
          Test Event
        </h1>
      </header>

      <div>
        <div class="field-name-field-date">
          <div>
            <div class="event-time">
              <span>6:30pm</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <section class="field-name-field-event-location">
          <h2 class="field-label">Location:&nbsp;</h2>
          <div>
            <div class="event-location">Test Location</div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <div class="field-name-body">
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>
                <img> Image here</img>
              </p>
              <p> Text here
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
  </article>
  <article>
  </article>
</div>
```

Example:
If the first article has a very long title and the header results in 300px height, also the other two articles (with shorter titles) should have 300px height. And consequently, the next item (event time) should start at the same height in all the articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more code (html/css) it is hard to see the traps to solve this question. But one aproach to your question is to set elements to same height with JS.

Lets say:
`article-elements` --> same height
`title-elements` --> same height
and so on ...

For this you can use a JS snippet like following:

```
function sameHeight( selector ){
    
    const $elements = document.querySelectorAll( selector );
    let maxHeight = 0;

    for(let actualElement of $elements){
        actualElement.style.height = '';
        maxHeight = ( actualElement.offsetHeight > maxHeight ) ? actualElement.offsetHeight : maxHeight;
    }
    
    for(let actualElement of $elements){
        actualElement.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
    }
    
}

// parameter selector 
// 'string'
// use every valid css selector (with '.' and '#' included to the string)
```

(Please adapt code to your necessities.)

Comment: Thank you! So let's say I want the <header> to be the same height. My selector will be ".event-content .node-header". I replace this value instead of "selector" and that's it?

Comment: @acaselli If you have different elements with selector `'.event-content .node-header'` and want to advise them same height then you can call `sameHeight('.event-content .node-header')`. I suggest to do it on `window.onload` event. Indeed that's it. But if you need/want additional action when window is resized you need to start it once more. On event `window.onresize`: do not forget to remove height-stylings from elements and start the function ...

Comment: @acaselli : I just updated the function and added an general removement of the/possible height sytlings. Now you are able to call function on `window.onload` and on `window.onresize` as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! Progress! So it works but it sets the height way too high. 2 divs are 46 px and one is 115px. When I enable the function, the height is set to 424px...how should I troubleshoot that?

Comment: @acaselli Hard to say without code ... maybe wrong selector ... which selects a higher element between the others? Maybe it is helpfull/easier to give the elements you would like to make same hight a separate class i.e. `.makeSameHeight` and call the function with this class.

Comment: How can I output the height of each element? I managed to output something and I checked that it outputs three elements so I think that the selector is correct...

Comment: EDIT: I got the printed value and I don't get where they come from... the important bit of the code is <div class="event-content">
      <header class="node-header"> I will try different selectors: '.event-content + header' ?

Comment: Open in Browser developer tools with keys `CTRL + SHIFT + C` when page is loaded. And maybe you like check if there is one of the selcted elements (or a child element) which has a class which sets the height. As the heights are set by JS to the elements the function does not remove heights which are set by css classes i.e. in a stylecheet.

Comment: You need to call the function with special selector for every group of elements which should get the same hight. So if `.event-content` is one group of elements call `sameHeight('.event-content')` and if `.node-header` is a separate group with different height you need to call the function a second time for this different group of elements.

Answer (score 0):

For such Condition you can simply use bootstrap's *Row, col* by bootstrap and gain desired result

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate deleniti quae, dolorem fugit temporibus! Beatae, reiciendis optio? Iure perferendis illo eveniet reprehenderit obcaecati tempore quae animi dolores porro tempora ipsam, cumque, rerum in consectetur omnis! Numquam, dolor est! Qui quasi placeat veniam voluptatum nostrum? Consectetur tempore ipsam modi perferendis vitae est ut quia totam, ipsum ducimus dolorem. Commodi doloribus alias tempore quam, pariatur saepe ad! Totam ex itaque harum soluta explicabo magnam, officia eos officiis porro dolores, quo dolorum? Amet saepe unde cupiditate mollitia sequi modi est veniam beatae porro cumque, natus ipsum rem excepturi nesciunt at quibusdam dolorem?</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, saepe!</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla ad rerum, odio quis omnis laborum corporis hic, pariatur, labore quidem odit adipisci veritatis ratione. Consectetur ducimus impedit provident eligendi delectus!</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor vel corporis laboriosam reiciendis aliquid harum laudantium autem nesciunt illo soluta!</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis quibusdam vel distinctio, adipisci recusandae necessitatibus deserunt sint mollitia consequatur tenetur consectetur at, facere doloribus unde. Non dicta ducimus rerum voluptate repellendus nam dolore ab, voluptatem sequi corrupti iste tempora possimus commodi distinctio quae, hic aspernatur deleniti omnis. Rerum, quaerat illo!</p></div>
        
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```